# What is the best way of saving a model, Loading it and continuing training?

Tags: python-3.x, keras, tensorflow2.0

I have gone through many answers here but found them partly correct or non-useful.

I have a keras/tensorflow model that needs to be trained. During this training, my model is to be

- Trained for some epochs
- Saved during each epoch
- Loaded any other time to continue training

How should I go about it?

Comment: When asking a question for which you have done partial research, it may be helpful to indicate what sources are you referring to (possibly including links) as well as to try to explicitly state why the approach you found does not work in your case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a simple method to do so. Although this method was proposed initially by other users, but there was always complaint from the seeker, regarding the resetting of model training and that their loaded model was training with a very low validation accuracy (and not where they had left off the last day). There is way around that.I would like to demonstrate this using an example:

Suppose I have models defined as:

```
def get_model_classif_nasnet():
    inputs = Input((224, 224, 3))
    #Other layers not shown here...
    model = Model(inputs, out)
    model.compile(optimizer=Adam(0.0001), loss=binary_crossentropy, metrics=['acc'])
    model.summary()
    return model
```

We will be saving our model progress after each epoch. For this, we use checkpoints. We will also be glad if the different saved checkpoints have relatable names.(i.e., the name should elaborate on the training environment it went through)

```
h5_path = "weights-improvement-{epoch:02d}-{val_loss:.4f}-{val_acc:.2f}.h5"

checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint(h5_path,
                             monitor='val_acc',
                             verbose=1,
                             save_best_only=True,
                             mode='max'
                            )
```

Now, lets use the above knowledge to save a model -

**1)** Train and save a model

**2)** Load it

**3)** Continue training

**1)**

```
#Initialize a model
old_model = get_model_classif_nasnet()

#Let's train it
 batch_size = 32

 history = old_model.fit_generator(
    #Training and Validation data...
    epochs=2, verbose=1,
    callbacks=[checkpoint],
    #Some other parameters (not necessarily present in your method)
    steps_per_epoch = len(train) // batch_size,
    validation_steps=len(val) // batch_size
)
```

This is how your progress should look like:
[image]

Notice the checkpoint being saved after epoch 1. Now let's assume that we end the training right midway the second epoch. So we have one checkpoint/model image saved as **.h5** file

**2)** Load it

```
#Again initialize a model
new_model = get_model_classif_nasnet()
```

**3)** Continue Training

```
#There is nothing new here
batch_size = 32

 history = new_model.fit_generator(
    #Training and Validation data...
    epochs=8, verbose=1,
    callbacks=[checkpoint],
    #Some other parameters (not necessarily present in your method)
    steps_per_epoch = len(train) // batch_size,
    validation_steps=len(val) // batch_size
)
```

So, that's it. The most important thing is, even after doing all this, you need to make sure that you **Keep the Learning Rate Low from the beginning** Perhaps you noticed 
*optimizer=Adam(0.0001)* This is the key over here. A user quoted *"It is happening because model.save(filename.h5) does not save the state of the optimizer. "*

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you need, you either use [`model.save()`](https://keras.io/getting-started/faq/#how-can-i-save-a-keras-model) or use a `ModelCheckPoint` [callback](https://keras.io/callbacks/).